# Excel 2013 VBA : remove the active filter from the active column (not all active filters)

Tags: excel, filter, excel-2013, vba

I'm able to activate a filter based on the currently selected cell (value) with:

```
Application.CommandBars("Cell").FindControl(id:=12232, Recursive:=True).Execute
```

This works, and I can use it several times in the same worksheet. However, I don't see a way to deactivate this filter for the currently selected column (active cell) without disabling all currently filtered columns.

Let's say I have three active filters (columns A, B, and C). I would like to disable the active filter from the currently selected cell/column. If my active cell is in col A and I run the macro, only the filter from col A would be set as inactive, while filters from columns B and C remain valid and active.

PS: this was one line of code in Excel 2003, and several lines in Excel 2007, but it doesn't run with Excel 2013.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
Dim rowcol As Long
Dim myRange As Range

Set myRange = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion

If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, myRange) Is Nothing Then
    rowcol = Intersect(ActiveCell, myRange).Column - myRange.Column + 1
    myRange.AutoFilter Field:=rowcol
End If
```

Comment: No, it might not work, it is working !

:-)

Many thanks