# Clear filter from column of the selected cell in the active table

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have a workbook with multiple sheets.  I'd like to create a macro that clears the filter from column of the currently selected cell.

I've been able to do it when I specify the table by name (below), but I'd like to substitute "Table1" with a reference to the active table.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=ActiveCell.Column
```

I also tried this and was not successful.[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999603/excel-2013-vba-remove-the-active-filter-from-the-active-column-not-all-active)

Answer (score 1):

- `ActiveCell.ListObject` is the active table.
- You don't need `Field` if you don't use other arguments (e.g. `Criterial1`).

*Clear all filters*

```
ActiveCell.ListObject.Range.AutoFilter
```

*Clear a filter with ActiveCell*

```
    With ActiveCell.ListObject.Range
        .AutoFilter Field:=.Column - ActiveCell.Column + 1
    End With
```

Comment: At first I thought this was working, but then I realized that it cleared the filter from all columns of the table, not just the one with the active cell.  Useful in other circumstances!

Comment: I have posted a snippet to clear a filter.

Answer (score 1):

To clear the filter from the selected column only, based on the active cell, try the following:

```
Sub ClearTableColumnFilter()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ActiveCell.ListObject

    If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
        tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=ActiveCell.Column - tbl.Range.Column + 1
    End If

End Sub
```

This will identify the correct column number, even if the table is not located in column A of the worksheet. Also, this will avoid "Run-time error '91'", which will otherwise occur if the active cell is not within a table.